# I am a beginner in python and currently I am studying loops. I am not able to answer a question

Tags: python, for-loop

Q-> WAP in python to take input of different numbers from the user if the number if less than 100 keep on taking the input from the user and if the number entered is bigger than 100 display the message "congratulations! The number you entered is bigger than 100". We have to do this using for loop. The program that I wrote is:

```
a=list(input("enter a number"))
for a1 in a:
    a=int(input())
    if int(a1)<100:
        print("try again")
        continue
    else:
        print("congratulation the number you entered is more than 100")
        break
```

but this program is faulty. How can I write the correct code?

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list as you iterate over it.  Why at `enter a number` do you convert the input to a list?  It seems that you want to get an integer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Code:-**

```
for _ in iter(int, 1):
    a=input("Enter the number: ")
    if int(a)>100:
        print("Congratulation")
        break
    print("Your number is lower")
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter the number: 80
Your number is lower
Enter the number: 43
Your number is lower
Enter the number: 89
Your number is lower
Enter the number: 97
Your number is lower
Enter the number: 101
Congratulation
```

Comment: `iter(int, 1)`? Why would you use this? This is totally obfuscating, and really not a reasonable way to do what the OP is trying to do. There are way more idiomatic ways make an infinite loop.

Comment: can you share!! idiomatic ways.. without the use of `iter` package.. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: `while True: ...` is the most idiomatic, or use `itertools` and an infinite iterator. Or you can just define an infinite iterator, `def iterate(): while True: yield` if you want to use a for-loop, but a while loop is very idiomatic

Comment: as OP problem give brief .. ` We have to do this using for loop.` @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build a list, since there's nothing you need the old numbers for.  The most straightforward way to do this would be a `while` loop, e.g.:

```
while int(input("enter a number ")) < 100:
    print("try again")
print("congratulations!  the number you entered is at least 100")
```

Using a `for` loop doesn't make as much sense because you don't have a set number of things to iterate over; you need to just keep retrying `while` the user is entering number that's too small.  If I had to use `for` here, though, I'd use something like `itertools.count`:

```
from itertools import count

for _ in count():
    if int(input("enter a number ")) >= 100:
        print("congratulations!")
        break
    print("try again")
```

Comment: `for line in sys.stdin:` could make sense.